# Развертка dev версии веб-приложения

Tags: git, администрирование, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Имеется некое веб-приложение php+mysql. Разработка ведется в git. Нужно сделать следующее.

Нужно реализовать две версии приложения. Production и dev. С файловой частью проблем нет. Достаточно вести две ветки в git: master - выкладывается на production, ветку dev на dev версию (можно по хукам, можно по крону, либо вручную... не суть). Но вот с базой есть проблема.

Требования такие:

1. Базы должны быть разными (то есть dev работает на одной копии БД, production на другой, боевой);
2. Необходим перенос снимка базы в обе стороны. Т.е. нажали волшебную кнопку, копия базы с production-а встала на dev, полностью ее заменив, и в обратную сторону также;
3. InnoDB;
4. Обе копии должны быть размещены на одном сервере физически.

Тут у меня мыслей, к сожалению, практически нет. Если мне память не изменяет, то у mysql нету ничего похожего на

```
COPY `database` INTO `new_database`
```

Единственная мысль - делать полный дамп одной базы, чистить вторую, лить первую в очищенную. Имхо не самое оптимальное решение (база под 5 гигов, это будет очень долго), но других вариантов я не знаю.

В связи с этим вопрос: может, у вас есть какое-либо более разумное решение? Например, как-то с репликацией поиграться или еще как-нибудь. Может, тупо копирование файлов в каталоге MySQL (но у innodb с этим сложности).

В общем, нужны какие-нибудь идеи, в какую сторону мне копать(

Comment: Какой смысл в копировании базы в обе стороны?

Comment: Можно сделать скрипт, который будет делать тестовую базу. Тогда можно будет генерить любые виды записей и тестировать их у себя.

Comment: KiTE, не сочтите за хамство, смысл есть, иначе бы вопрос я не задавал. Причем нужно сделать именно так, как я попытался описать, другие варианты не подходят, мы уже думали над этим.

Впрочем даже если в одну сторону, то это сути не меняет, других решений, кроме как делать полный дамп и его импортировать, я до сих пор не нашел.

Comment: @IntellectSys, ну так расшифруйте этот самый смысл. Возможно, для решения вашего вопроса уже есть какие-то общепринятые практики. Если вам нужно переносить данные в dev-окружение, то это одно решение, если структуру - другое.

Comment: @IntellectSys наиболее "внутреннее" решение, которое приходит в голову:

1. Получить имена всех таблиц, хоть из бд, хоть из хардкода
2. `SHOW CREATE TABLE` для каждой
3. Выстроить их в нужном порядке, чтобы атрибуты, к которым привязаны FK, существовали на момент объявления этих самых fk.
4. INSERT INTO ... SELECT для каждой

Вряд ли это будет гораздо быстрее дампа.

Альтернативно можно вести миграции, тогда пункты 1-3 отпадают.

Comment: @KiTE, это будет непросто) можно сказать, это требование заказчика.

В общем dev версия представляет собой что-то типа песочницы. Т.е. пришел заказчик, сделал снапшот из прода в песочницу, поэксперементировал (какую-то инфу добавил, что-то отредактировал и т.д), если результат понравился - залил текущее состояние песочницы обратно на прод. Если не понравился, то снова делаем снапшот из прода в песочницу. Изменения могут быть любыми, вплоть до изменения структуры таблиц.

Разработка также ведется через эту песочницу, и если все человека устраивает, то результат пушится на прод.

Comment: @Etki, спасибо за идею, попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем тратить огромное количество человеко-часов на поиски решения, которое вам навязывается заказчиком - советую реалистично оценить размеры базы данных. Импорт/Экспорт любой сколько-либо значимой БД может занимать часы - это однозначно не "нажал волшебную кнопку и база за 1 секунду скопировалась", а значит вам надо включить коммуникационные навыки и объяснить заказчику что то, что он просит - технически не реализуемо.

Если же совсем совсем приспичит - делайте так:

- Выключаем MySQL (помня, что выключение надо это сделать так, чтобы все операции из буфера записались на диск в файлы данных - а иначе скопировать базу у вас не получится)
- Копируем файлы InnoDB из одной БД в другую
- Включаем MySQL

Comment: Кстати, если продакшн и дев физически на одном сервере - можно доустановить на него оперативки и делать манипуляции с дампом на RAM-диске. Но это только временное решение. Про SSD молчу - на них запись 5гиг проходит достаточно шустро.

Answer (score 0):

Для быстрых дампов БД может подойти Percona XtraBackup из Percona Toolkit http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup

Репликация не думаю, что будет быстрее. Слейву придется достаточно долго "догонять" мастер.